# Cisco Catalyst 3560 PoE 48 with setting interface to auto qos voip trust

Tags: cisco, switch, qos, cisco-catalyst

All I'm trying to do is copy the running-config from a Cisco Catalyst 2560 PoE 24, to a Catalyst 3560 PoE 48. This is f0/1 from the original switch:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 40
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 98
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out
 mls qos trust cos
 auto qos trust             <----------------------
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
```

On the previous 2560 it was set to "auto qos voip trust" (the arrow); I get the following error when I import the running-config into the 3560:

AutoQoS Error: AutoQoS already configured

I turned off autoqos with a **debug auto qos** and a **no mls qos** globally, removed the **auto qos trust**  then a **auto qos voip trust**

I received no warnings after entering the last command but on a show config, it's still not listing the voip trust.  Any ideas where to look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit hard to follow what has happened based on your description - but try "show auto qos interface fastethernet 0/1" and see what it tells you

You can find a good description of everything Auto QoS will configure and its expected behaviors @ http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12-2_53_se/configuration/guide/3750xscg/swqos.html#wp1231112

You must be running IOS 15 - they changed the command to "auto qos trust" and removed the VOIP sub command.  This change is described @ http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/15-2_1_e/configuration/guide/scg3750x/swqos.html#wp1739670

In short - you're fine; 'auto qos trust' is a proper substitution to 'auto qos voip trust'.

Comment: Jason, I still get a auto qos trust, rather than a auto qos voip trust.

Comment: Answered better above now that I understand your question